Loading ETag property when retrieve items as a stream in SharePoint
I am trying to read the SharePoint list contents using RenderListDataAsStream as below:
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetList(@listUrl)/RenderListDataAsStream?@listUrl=%27%2Fsites%2Fteam-a%2Flists%2FList%27
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata"
Content-Type: "application/json;odata=nometadata"

{
  "parameters": {
    "AddRequiredFields": "true",
    "DatesInUtc": "true",
    "RenderOptions": 17
  }
}

RenderListDataAsStream body parameters are set as below:
Parameters = new StreamDataRequest.StreamDataParameters
{
    DatesInUtc = true,
    ViewXml = "<View DefaultView='TRUE' Url='URL'>
                  <ViewFields>
                     <FieldRef Name='Title'/>                
                     <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
                     ....
                   </ViewFields>
               </View>",
    AddRequiredFields = true,
    Paging = pagingToken
}

I am trying to read the ETag property for the files I am loading using the request above and when I add <FieldRef Name='ETag' /> or <FieldRef Name='.etag' />, the property is not populated.
Using ctx.Web.GetFileById(); to load the file and read the ETag, is not efficient as it requires a loop over the loaded files and affects the performance.
I am trying to find out if I can load the ETag property in the ViewXML as a part of my CAML query.
The SharePoint is using the same API call to load its list information and in the response, there is ".etag" property that I am interested in:


Since UniqueId and DocConcurrencyNumber are returned as every list item properties for files, the eTag can be generated following the format below:
"{UniqueId},DocConcurrencyNumber"

Since DocDoncurrencyNumber increases after every change made on the file, it can be used to trace file changes.
